# Callback is not firing in ExtJs Store

Tags: javascript, extjs, dom-events

I have the following code, but it is not working. The `callback` never fires, and so is load listener.

```
var someDS = new Ext.data.Store({
    proxy : new Ext.data.HttpProxy({url : 'someUrl', method : 'GET'}),
    reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({} ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']),
    callback : function(options, success, response) {
         alert(response);
         // some code
    },
    listeners: {
         load : function() {
            alert("load");
            // some code
         }
     }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your reader definition doesn't look correct to me: is the "{} ['aaa','bbb','ccc']" bit fine?

anyway, this code works with extjs 3.2:

```
var mystore = new Ext.data.Store({
    url: '/your/url/',
    autoLoad: true,
    reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({
        root: 'rows',
        fields: [ 'id', 'field1', 'field2' ]
    }), 
    listeners: {
        load: function(t, records, options) {
            console.log('test ok');
            for (var i=0; i<records.length; i++) {
                console.log(String.format('record {0} = {1}', i, records[i].data.id));
            }   
        }   
    }   
});
```

it works with the following json string returned by the server call at '/your/url/':

```
{
    "rows": [
        {
            "id": 17, 
            "field1": "Emiliano", 
            "field2": 1 
        }, 
        {
            "id": 18, 
            "field1": "Luca", 
            "field2": 3 
        }         
    ], 
    "total": 2
}
```

- do not confuse the load method and
  the load event;
- do not forget the 'root' parameter in
  the reader definition (well, actually
  it's not necessary to have the 'test
  ok' string printed, but without it
  you won't get the ids printed by the
  for loop)